# Access Unable to Count all Selected Listbox Items

Tags: vba, ms-access

I am using Multiselect (Extended) to select items in a list box. With the focus on the listbox, after I use the Shift+DownArrowKey to select more than one item, a count of items selected never includes the last one in the selected list. 
I am using the On Key Up and Down triggers for the arrow keys to perform the count (For Each ItemIndex In Me.List40.ItemsSelected).

While the focus is on the listbox, this procedure does not seem to update the list to include the last selection. Is there a way to get around this?

Answer (score 1):

If you're only looking to obtain the count of selected items, you can use the `Count` property of the `ItemsSelected` collection:

```
List40.ItemsSelected.Count
```

Comment: I AM using the count property - try it yourself and you will find the last one selected will not be included.

Comment: Let me clarify this - what you suggest does work. However, I need to test each selected item for a specific value in the associated table record and then increment a count variable when the test succeeds. For some reason, the ItemIndex does not include the last item.

Comment: Further clarification - I have no problem getting the proper counts after leaving the focus of the list box. The problem occurs when I try to stay in the list box (to continue selecting multiple items) and use the itemindex. The index is not updating to include the last item selected. Before and after lisbox update do not fix this - what is triggered after each item is selected, and can I use that?

Comment: After digging, I found the answer to my problem. I should not have been using On Key Down to process the list - it turns out the On Key Up procedure processes list changes before completing the procedure, Silly error, but I appreciate your efforts.